# xQuery and T-SQL to Extract Data

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

Got some basic XML as a XML datatype within SQL 2005. One record/row looks like this

```
<doc>
  <level1>

    <level2>
      <name>James</name>
      <age>12</age>
    </level2>

    <level2>
      <name>John</name>
      <age>23</age>
    </level2>

  </level1>
</doc>
```

When I perform some basic T_SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1 
DocumentXML.query('data(//doc/name)'),
DocumentXML.query('data(//doc/age)')
FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[TBLNAME]
```

I get

```
ID  |  Name     | Age
----------------------
1   | JamesJohn | 1223
```

How do I re-write the T-SQL so it displays as

```
ID  |  Name  |  Age
--------------------
1   |  James |  12
2   |  John  |  23
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example doesn't work for me; the second level2 opens with `</level2>`. And `//doc/name` doesn't exist; might be `//doc/level1/level2/name`.

Here's an example of how to retrieve a rowset from an XML:

```
declare @t table (id int identity, doc xml)
insert @t (doc) values (
    '<doc>
      <level1>

        <level2>
          <name>James</name>
          <age>12</age>
        </level2>

        <level2>
          <name>John</name>
          <age>23</age>
        </level2>

      </level1>
    </doc>')

SELECT  x.a.value('(name)[1]','varchar(50)') as col1
,       x.a.value('(age)[1]','varchar(50)') as col2
FROM    @t t
cross apply
        t.doc.nodes('//level2') x(a)
```

This prints:

```
col1     col2
James    12
John     23
```

Comment: Thanks - however my XML is stored as a XML datatype within the row, how would this then work?

Comment: @Janusz Jasinski: You can use a `cross apply` to excute the `nodes` operation for each row.  Example added to answer.